# How to fetch with multiple query parameters Genereic API view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

so I am building an API and i want to fetch based on multiple parameters.

Here is the code base.

The Url path:

```
path('<str:order_id>/consumers/', SingleConsumerTradeAPIView.as_view(), name="single-consumer-trade" ),
path('<str:order_id>/producers/', SingleProducerTradeAPIView.as_view(), name="single-producer-trade" ),
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from authApi.models import User

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Trade(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='consumer',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producer = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='producer',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='trades',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, max_length=255, decimal_places=2)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    energyQuantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, max_length=255, decimal_places=2)
    startTime = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    stopTime = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Serializers.py:

```
class TradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = ('id',
                  'order_id',
                  'startTime',
                  'stopTime',
                  'price',
                  'consumer_id',
                  'producer_id',
                  'location',
                  'energyQuantity',
                )


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trades = TradeSerializer(read_only=True, many= True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id',
                  'trades',
                  'date',
                )
```

What i tried:

Views

```
class SingleProducerTradeAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class=TradeSerializer
    queryset = Trade.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    lookup_fields = ('order_id', 'producer_id')

    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order_id = kwargs.get('order_id')
        user = self.request.user
        try:
            trades = Trade.objects.filter(order_id=order_id,consumer_id=user)
        except Trade.DoesNotExist: 
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'The user does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND) 
        order_serializer = TradeSerializer(trades, many=True) 
        return JsonResponse(order_serializer.data, safe=False) 
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(consumer_id=self.request.user)
```

I want to be able to fetch from the list of trades(via the trade model and serializers) using the order_id and the producer_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can directly use the **get_queryset** method and you will definitely get the parameters from **kwargs** of the get_queryset method and you can remove the **queryset** variable from the class and directly hit the query in the get_queryset method. It will save time by hitting the database only once.
there is no need for **lookup_fields** too so you can remove it.

```
class SingleConsumerTradeAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class=TradeSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    lookup_fields = ('order_id', 'producer_id')

    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Trade.objects.filter(order_id=kwargs.get('order_id'),producer_id=
self.request.user.id)
```

Comment: self.request.user always return logged in user_id, yeah?

Comment: not user_id but it returns user instance instead. you can get the user_id by self.request.user.id, here you can write both like producer = self.request.user or producer_id = self.request.user.id

Answer (score 0):

Django will send the parameters from the URL into the view functions are keyword arguments (`**kwargs`)

```py
class SingleConsumerTradeAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class=TradeSerializer
    queryset = Trade.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    lookup_fields = ('order_id', 'producer_id')

    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order_id = kwargs.get('order_id')
        user_id = kwargs.get('user_id')

        # do some work with order_id and user_id
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(order_id=self.request.user,producer_id=
self.request.user)
```

Comment: so on the URL path, I removed the user_id because `self.request.user` already knows the user(who is authenticated), but now why do I have to create the function list(`def list`) when there is get_queryset, (I am a beginner, please pardon my ignorance)?